# Binding label content to a value in nested class not in Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

My view (InformationView) Binded to InformationViewModel and I use a nested class to maintain current Bank

My nested class :

```
public class MainController : NotificationObject
{
    public MainController()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO implement 
    }


    public static MainController Instance
    {
        get { return Nested.instance; }
    }

    private BankModel _currentBank;

    public BankModel CurrentBank
    {
        get { return _currentBank; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentBank== value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _currentBank= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentBank);
        }
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly MainController instance = new MainController();
    }
}
```

My BankModel :

```
    private string _name ="test";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>Name);
        }
    }
```

My XAML

```
xmlns:Controller="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controller" 
/****/
<Label Content="{Binding Controller:MainController.CurrentBank.Name}"/>
```

first I can't see the "test" in my label and if I execute I change this value and always my label is empty, how I do this with the correct approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a combination of "Path" and "Source" in your binding declaration.  You also need to alert the binding engine to the fact that you're accessing static members.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static Controller:MainController.Instance}, Path=CurrentBank.Name}" />
```